# Always show quoted text in Gmail

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to disable Gmail's default behaviour of hiding what it thinks is quoted text and always have the whole body of every message visible?

Comment: All the 'solutions' I've seen involve you having to take gmail out of "conversation view". Either permanently in Mail Settings, or for the current thread by altering the subject when you reply so that a 'new' conversation is created and the quoted text is shown. However, neither of these are what I'd call a solution since you lose functionality ie. the conversation!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, this feature is not available.

[Proving the absence of something can be a challenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence), but in this case I'm relying on a sampling of discussions of this subject in the Gmail Product Forums where no solution is proposed, and Google Support is totally quiet.  Not posting all links here, but some include:

1. http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/X8f5WCBppuA
2. http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/1lj3GqJoxxw
3. http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/composing-and-sending-messages/kddl4Tz9MCQ

Comment: Hey Benj, could you add some sources to your conclusion of why you think the feature is not available?

Comment: @phwd See revised answer.  Does this help?